# Why is the full URL in my Google result not showing?

Tags: seo, google, permalinks

When I do a Google search for my individual event pages, the page is usually found but the URL shown under the title seems to always link to my events index. (Title links to the individual page are OK)

My site is the bottom example. How do I go about getting my slugged URL to show as per the example above it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As indicated [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) by Google:

> Our systems analyze the link structure of your site to find shortcuts
>   that will save users time and allow them to quickly find the
>   information they're looking for.

Make sure you're not using that URL with a slug in your site, *sitemap.xml*, or one is linking back to your site, and that there isn't a URL rewrite rule in your web server doing this either. Also be sure to provide the full URL in your *sitemap.xml* with a high [priority](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) value specified for it.

You can add a [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) to the page to let Google know the preferred URL is the full one, and then submit the full URL using the [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en) tool to request Google crawl and index it again.

Lastly, you can demote links as covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en), however that would likely not be beneficial to you.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason this has shown up is because you have breadcrumbs on your website (The "Home / Events / Not The Beatles" part). This is a fairly strong indicator to the search engines, and you'd have to remove this to prevent the breadcrumb URL showing up. Personally, I'd leave it as is, because I think it is more useful to users.

Comment: Interesting, I was actually thinking of dropping the breadcrumbs very soon as users don't navigate too deeply into the site and they don't fit too well with some slight redesigns.